# Mercurial update not working

Tags: mercurial

I'm using Mercurial 1.7.2 Windows

I have a local repo where I copied some files into.Now I'd like to remove these files. I tried to use revert and update but those files are still there.

I tried these commands

```
hg revert --all
```

nothing, files stll there

```
hg update null
```

still nothing

I ran these commands from my repo using the commandline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [PurgeExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PurgeExtension). It's a plugin for Mercurial. Purge is shipepd with Mercurial but by default is this plugin inactive. Enable it and then use:

```
hg purge
```

Comment: And the reason why you need this extension is, that Mercurial never touches files it doesn't know. So reverting only affects *tracked* files.

Answer (score 1):

Try `hg status`. If it lists the files you copied there as unknown, all you need to do is delete them manually, as mercurial isn't tracking them anyway. Otherwise, you need to tell mercurial to forget or delete them from the repo. (e.g. `hg forget foo.bar`). Conversely, mercurial will not track new files until you tell it to, so if you copy files into your local repo, you need to do `hg add foo.bar` and then `hg commit` to make mercurial track them.

Answer (score 0):

try:
 hg remove

or look into the hg backout command